# Mortarboard badge misnamed?

Tags: discussion, badges

Would it not be better called the "[Glass ceiling](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Glass_ceiling)" badge to reflect you bumping your metaphorical reputation head against it?

I just can't get my head around "Mortarboard". Perhaps it's the bump and I have concussion...

Answer (score 30, accepted):

How about calling it the "Al Gore" badge? You can get as many extra votes as you like, and somehow it doesn't help...

Comment: I'm still convinced that if we recount enough, I'll have more rep points than you. I think a lot of users tried to upvote me but didn't understand the system, so they ended up upvoting you instead.

Comment: If only you could save up all those lost votes, and store them somewhere safe and secure... Maybe in some kind of box, perhaps with a lock on it... A sort of "lock box"...

Comment: @gnostradamus: No, if you lock on a boxed value you'll end up getting a different reference every time, so the lock will be useless. Oh wait, you weren't talking about C#?

Comment: Either "Good enough: It beats Mortarboard" or "Vote to close: Too localised". hmmmm

Comment: Let's keep politics out of this, please.

Comment: @tvanfosson: It wasn't a serious suggestion. I would hope that the lighter side of the 2000 election could be seen 9 years later...

Answer (score 12):

The name [Mortarboard](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mortarboard) refers to the hat worn at a graduation.

So, congratulations! You have your SO [GED](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/General_Educational_Development).

Comment: Ah well see,  I bought my degree off eBay so obviously missed something...

Comment: to me, the concept of "graduation" here is relevant: if you can hit the daily rep cap, you have definitely mastered the essentials of Stack Overflow. Well, that, or you got really lucky, but such is the way the world works...

Comment: I'd steer away from geopolitacally specific terms as much as possible, before reading this reply I thought mortarboard refers to metallic plate actual mortars are stuck on to and to even take this even more out of context, this is what most Finns put on their heads at graduation: http://cartinafinland.fi/kuvapankki/imagebank/image/36/36338/Ylioppilaslakki.jpg

Comment: Until @Jeff spoke up I thought you were onto something.  Rep **cap**, **cap** and gown, ah well...

Comment: @Esko: Would you prefer we call it 'the-thing-american-kids-put-on-their-head-and-not-Finns'?

Comment: Well that'd be better actually since it's descriptive and doesn't require extra effort to figure out.

Comment: @Esko:  FYI, I think what you're referring to is called a "base plate" over here.  It wouldn't suggest a cap, since after all it's what's at the bottom of the mortar.  I wonder how many people in SO know something about military mortars but not the English terminology.

Comment: Most of the Finnish male population at least thanks to mandatory service :) Admittedly we are a minority but it's still very confusing.

Answer (score 8):

Glass Ceiling refers to the discrimination of women in the workplace.

It is referring to an invisible (yet real) upper limit that women cannot breakthrough in the corporate world.

It is not an appropriate name for this badge.

Comment: It has other meanings too: not exclusively about women in the workplace.

Comment: @gbn - maybe, but that meaning's the first one that I thought of.

Comment: a glass ceiling is a limit anybody faces, weather it be based on gender, skin colour or just social skill. 
Woman just happen to be the ones most public talked about.

Comment: @Simeon: NO. Anybody is not a minority. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Glass_ceiling

Comment: I've never thought of it as applying to women, *per se* - but to anyone who either limits themselves, or allows themselves to be limited by the environment they're in (*a la* a high-school dropout working for a company that won't promote folks without a college degree)

Comment: Last I looked, men were a minority, FWIW.  Anyway, "glass ceiling" generally refers to an unstated and implicit policy.  If your company says you can't be promoted without a college degree, that's not a glass ceiling.  If after a while you notice that nobody without a college degree (or a Y chromosome) is ever promoted above a certain line, that is.  Since the rep cap is explicit and published, it isn't a glass ceiling.

Answer (score 6):

The badge should be named "Stack Overflow"

Simple, sweet, self-referential.

What's not to love?

Comment: if you see a badge called stack overflow, will you instantly think that the user who had it popped their rep cap, or something else related to the site? :D

Comment: @CrazyJugglerDrummer: Yes.

Comment: Stack overflow! Great! ;-) +1

Answer (score 5):

It's a *cap*, 'ya see?

Comment: A *cap* could be many things http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cervical_cap

Answer (score 0):

It sounds too similar to an interrogation technique. Yes, the web site is all about getting answers, but they're supposed to be given voluntarily!